# Is it possible for a surplus of electrons to be generated during a chemical reaction?

Tags: redox

I was wondering whether a chemical reaction can produce excess electrons after the completion of the reaction, in addition to generating by-products (chemical compounds) and heat.

In other words, can there be instances where the reactants share the required electrons among themselves and release surplus electrons to achieve a stable configuration?

Comment: If a chemical reaction produces electrons, it is not a reaction. It is a half-reaction. One example is the oxidation of aluminium Al to Al(III), according to :$$\ce{Al -> Al^{3+} + 3 e-}$$

Comment: Well, you may dissolve sodium in liquid ammonia and get something which kinda can be described as _"free electrons"_, or more correctly, _"solvated electrons"_. This, I believe, is the closest that you can get.

Comment: It is certainly possible to generate a *local* excess of electrons *during* a reaction but not to leave an excess at the end. The electrostatic forces of *any* excess are large and will cause something else to happen. For example, the temporary excess of electrons generated when lumps of sodium are thrown into water is the primary driver of the resulting explosion (a coulomb explosion).

Comment: What " surplus electrons"? You don't magically summon electrons there's only what was earlier.

Comment: The thing remotely similar is the spatially separated releasing and capturing electrons in galvanic or electrolytic cells. But the local net charge is controlled  by enormous eventual potential change in case of charge disbalance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. It happens all the time when [an electropositive metal is dissolved into an appropriate solvent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvated_electron). Ammonia is the best known solvent capable of holding such **solvated electrons,** but other amine solvents such as ethylenediamine can do so as well. In synthetic applications the electrons are consumed again when another material is added to set off an additional reaction.

Water can in principle have solvated electrons too, but in that solvent the electrons react so quickly that they are difficult to catch experimentally. So if you are studying aqueous redox chemistry, you find that the electrons are treated as virtual or transient species and therefore must be balanced out of any observed chemical reaction.